# Can we cascade multiple MapReduce jobs in Hadoop Streaming (lang: Python)

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am using Python and have to work on following scenario using Hadoop Streaming:
a) Map1->Reduce1->Map2->Reduce2
b) I dont want to store intermediate files
c) I dont want to install packages like Cascading, Yelp, Oozie. I have kept them as last option.

I already went through the same kind of discussion on SO and elsewhere but could not find an answer wrt Python. Can you please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> b) I dont want to store intermediate files
>
> c) I dont want to install packages like Cascading, Yelp, Oozie.

Any reason why? Based on the response, a better solution could be provided.

Intermediates files cannot be avoided, because the o/p of the previous Hadoop job cannot be streamed as i/p to the next job.  Create a script like this

> run streaming job1
> if job1 is not success then exit
> run streaming job2
> if job2 is success them remove o/p of job1 else exit
> run streaming job3
> if job3 is succcess them remove o/p of job2 else exit

Comment: - Because I have just started learning Hadoop (for a project) and this how I am supposed to go

- For "job1", "job2" etc do I need to define some jobs?

- And as you mentioned, I will try your approach. But in this case, just writing a script will do? Am I not suppose to use it with some command line like "hadoop *streaming*.jar -input <ip-dir> -ouput <o/p-dir> -mapper <map> -reducer <red>"

Answer (score 2):

Why not using MapReduce frameworks for python streaming, like Dumbo https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo/wiki/Short-tutorial, or MRJob http://packages.python.org/mrjob/

For example, with dumbo, your pipe would be:

```
job.add_iter(Mapper1, Reducer1)
job.add_iter(Mapper2, Reducer2)
```