# Is there a good library that helps chain MapReduce jobs using Hadoop Streaming and Python?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, machine-learning, hadoop-streaming, mrjob

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860214/can-we-cascade-multiple-mapreduce-jobs-in-hadoop-streaming-lang-python) question answers part of my question but not completely.

How do I run a script that manages this, is it from my local filesystem? Where exactly do things like MrJob or Dumbo come into picture? Are there any more alternative?

I am trying to run K-Means where each iterations (a MapReduce job) output will be the input to the next iteration with Hadoop Streaming and Python.

I do not have much experience and any information should help me make this work.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not very tightly coupled with Python then you have a very good option. There is one project from Cloudera called "[Crunch](https://github.com/cloudera/crunch)" that allows us to create pipelines of MR jobs easily. it's a java library that provides a framework for writing, testing, and running MapReduce pipelines, and is based on Google's FlumeJava library.

Answer (score 1):

There is another non-python option. [Graphlab](http://graphlab.org/toolkits/clustering/) is an open source project to produce free implementations of scalable machine learning algorithms on multicore machine and clusters. There is an implemented fast scalable version of the Kmeans++ algorithm included in the package. See [Graphlab](http://graphlab.org/toolkits/clustering/) for details.

[image]

Clustering API of graphlab can be found [here](http://docs.graphlab.org/clustering.html) .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good applications for [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) it has also streaming option but I'm afraid it only works with Scala, but they have Python API, definitively worth a try, it is not that difficult to use ( at least the tutorials) and it can scale at large.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use GraphLab Create (in Python) running on Hadoop to do what you describe. The [clustering toolkit](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/graphlab.toolkits.clustering.html) can help implement the K-Means part. You can coordinate/script it from your local machine and use the [graphlab.deploy API](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/graphlab.deploy.html) to run the job on Hadoop.